# How can we improve the quality of discussions in the Mobile Development collective?

Tags: discussion, collectives, discussions-space

I'm in the Mobile Development collective and the [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions) seem to be adding questionable value. Sorting by highest score shows there's a few opinion-based discussions that fit well, but for a community with nearly 5K members the top post having only 10 score and 11 replies seems underwhelming. Sorting by new shows why participation may be low - Posts are not created often, and when they are they're often low-quality posts that are heavily downvoted. Many of them are questions that if posted outside of discussions would be quickly closed as too broad or off-topic.

Briefly skimming through some other collectives shows that this is not a universal problem - Other similar-sized collectives such as [R](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/beta/discussions) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php) appear to have better-quality posts, while [NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions) seems to have a similar problem with post quality.

What can be done to address this problem and encourage higher-quality discussion in this collective?

Comment: Seeding is probably extremely important (creating a critical mass). Otherwise, they end up as ghost towns with the occasional unloading of trash questions from the nearby big town "Stack Overflow".

Comment: I guess you should go back to the reasons why it was thought that Discussions was useful including the motivating research results.

Answer (score 12):

> but for a community with nearly 5K members the top post having only 10 score and 11 replies seems underwhelming.

Some perspective:

As I post this, to find a question with 10 score on the main site I have to go back 8 hours. Getting that level of engagement involves 24 *million* accounts (there's no good way to know how many of them are active or compare that activity level to the 5k users in a relatively new collective, I think).

Questions with 10+ answers are much rarer - understandably, since it isn't really desirable to have that kind of interaction normally (the main space explicitly *isn't* for discussion).

If I filter to the `[python]` tag (more than 2 million questions and one of the biggest tags on the site, but possibly attracts below-average-quality questions in recent years) I have to go back 3 weeks to find a question with 10+ score - right about as far as the top discussion you're talking about.

The really popular questions in the main space are much older, because it takes a long time for people to filter in and decide to upvote something that's already highly upvoted. Although every now and then you get something that gets quite popular rather quickly. IMX these tend to be questions about [a common, one-off problem with installing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213053).

My take is that these discussions simply aren't getting the views that would be necessary for higher scores. In the long run, it seems that the standout questions on Stack Overflow are still looking at something like ~1k views per upvote, after the first few votes from more active curators.

The one question with a 10 score in the mobile collective is a real standout (the next few are at +3), especially getting that response from only about 200 views. It seems to describe a topic of extremely high interest to a very specific group of people.

I see no clear evidence of a quality problem here.

Comment: *"I see no clear evidence of a quality problem here."* I don't think I have a way to find deleted discussions, but I remember there previously being a bunch of much lower quality discussions that I don't see in the list anymore.

Comment: Questions get posted orders of magnitude more frequently than discussions so there's a lot more to compete with imo, not exactly an apples to apples comparison

Comment: Plus if you look at any new posts in the collective they get _heavily_ downvoted, much more than in other collectives. Probably should've focused on that bit in my original question.

Comment: I mean, the newest MD collective discussion posts are all either spam or images of flutter doctor that literally tells you what to do next to resolve it, or how to use GPT to fix a memory leak... not exactly the pinnacle of quality. There's not a switch we can flip that will get people to *instead* create high-quality, interesting discussions,

Comment: I didn't say the quality is adequate, I only said that these vote totals don't evidence a problem.

Answer (score 9):

My opinion on this is that it's hard for users to make quality posts when there's no prominent and clear guidelines for what makes a good discussion question. While the [Discussions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines) page exists, it takes two clicks to get there from the discussions home page and it's unlikely people will find it, especially since when creating a new post the "guidelines" box simply reads:

> Use discussion posts to ask a question or start a conversation about Mobile Development.

Community-specific guidelines that are prominently displayed when creating posts would help address this issue, as well as summarizing the general guidelines on the post creation page.

The lack of specific flag reasons like in Q&A posts also makes it difficult to flag low-quality posts - Because of the lack of clear guidelines I'm not sure when to flag posts and when I do flag I can't specify a reason. Having flag categories based on the general and community-specific guidelines would help.

Comment: Hmm… seems odd to me thst the guidelines box would directly state its for asking questions, when discussions are expressly not for things that are good Q&A candidates. That could be *some* of the problem, but the latest few posts from the past 24 hours are literally spam that hasn’t been handled yet, the new flag system that should be coming soon will hopefully fix that

Comment: @KevinB - The first question I clicked on was literal spam, for a blog post, which I found within 3 minutes of searching.

Comment: @KevinB "discussions are expressly not for things that are good Q&A candidates" - I've mainly noticed that "questions" asked in discussions are specifically questions that are low-quality or would be closed as off-topic if posted as a Q&A

Answer (score 8):

Are there topics people in the mobile dev community wish to discuss? From my perspective, someone who sits somewhat outside of that community but have done *some* mobile app development in the past, most content I see around mobile dev is fairly… clickbaity and full of seemingly dated content or opinion pieces that I for whatever reason feel like I can’t trust.

I guess what I’m trying to say is… if you want there to be meaningful, interesting discussions in the collective, create them. They aren’t going to just happen, someone has to step up to the plate and do it. PHP and R collectives both have highly active experts that are fostering these kinds of discussions.

Comment: I don't particularly know what kind of discussions I'd *want* to see, but I *hate* all the "What's the best dev framework" or "What your favorite editor" stuff. They're surely likely to lead to... discussion and upvotes, but they're not all that useful to me if I was looking for the solution that would be best for *my* situation. Which tool is the most popular is rarely the best metric to cling to because that changes almost yearly.