# Quality of discussions in collectives

Tags: discussion, collectives, discussions-space

In particular I'm looking at the mobile dev collective here, maybe this is uniquely bad. But looking at the discussions- on the first 2 pages of discussions, more than 80% are downvoted, most of them heavily. Some of them should be questions, others don't or barely touch programming. Of the few upvoted questions, I'm dubious about whether it isn't sockpuppets (for example 1 upvoted discussion is from a 1-reputation poster with a single sub-200-reputation responder). Right now I'm not looking at that section of the site anymore as it's a waste of my time- there's no value there. I'm curious what the purpose of this section of the site is envisioned to have, and whether it's actually meeting that purpose. I'm also curious if this is common across collectives or if mobile dev is just particularly bad.

Comment: For the purpose of collectives, try reading e.g. the announcements for the feature. As for "there is a lot of low-quality content on Stack Overflow", I don't understand what it's supposed to accomplish to point this out. Might as well say it rains a lot in England.

Comment: PHP is not really any better. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427358/how-to-prevent-question-asking-in-collective-discussions) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427394/new-users-posting-spam-with-links)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly why discussions, opinions etc were originally not allowed on StackOverflow.  Until some genius decided to make a discussions (collectives) section that is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we improve the quality of discussions in the Mobile Development collective?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427209/how-can-we-improve-the-quality-of-discussions-in-the-mobile-development-collecti)

Comment: As far as purpose: my guess is that's two-fold, one is welcoming, _"Your s**t opinion based question was closed? That's because it wasn't asked in collectives, you can ask it there and no-one will close it"_, two is monetization, _"Does your organization want a nice collective with an open discussion space that bears no resemblance to a dumpster fire whatsoever, pay us now and you can get one on Stack Overflow!"_

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77599169/restful-api-web-services).

Comment: Have a peek at [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427394/new-users-posting-spam-with-links-in-collective-discussions) which I think would be relevant.